# Why Isn't My 2D Box Collider Working?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm making boundaries for the characters in my 2d game in unity 5. I added box colliders to the borders and my characters but the characters don't stop when they run into the other borders.

Comment: is there any setting that needs to be enabled or something?

Comment: Going to need a bit more than that.  Show the OnCollisionEnter, or some sort of code of any kind.

Comment: im just using the built in box collider for unity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have much experience of Unity 5, but probably these things work similarly than with old versions of Unity.

Colliders can be used for stopping things to go inside each other without writing your own OnCollisionEnter function.

So there must be some other problem. Check that:

1. Colliders are same type. 2D and 3D colliders don't detect collisions with each other.
2. At least one participant of the collision needs to have rigidbody component attached.
3. Check that `is trigger` is not selected on any of the colliders
4. Pause the game and check in the scene view that the green boxes of the colliders actually colliding
5. Check the layers of the gameobjects and check if they are should collide because of [the layer based collision](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)

Answer (score -1):

When the colliders intersect it will trigger an OnCollisionEnter event.  You need to tell it what to do after that.  It could be setting the velocity to 0 in the case of a ball hitting the wall, or it could be awakening enemies in the case of a player walking into a trap.  You have to define the behavior.

Comment: With this method the player would stop when it enters the border. But after that it can continue to any direction. I cannot see any easy way to fix it, if you are writing your own OnCollision functions. The idea is correct for awakening enemies though.